# Storing multiple values in buffer

Tags: java, multithreading, buffer

I have a consumer and producer class and I'm using an unsynchronised buffer. I want the producer and the consumer both be able to store a value in the buffer, and they shouldn't overwrite each other. I also want the consumer to be able able to access the value set in the buffer and be able to change it. Is it possible to do that?

**Buffer**

```
public interface Buffer{
public void set( int value ) throws InterruptedException; 

public int get() throws InterruptedException; 
}
```

**unsynchronizedBuffer**

```
public void set( int value) throws InterruptedException{
   System.out.printf( "Producer writes\t%2d ", value );
   buffer = value;
}

public int get() throws InterruptedException{
   System.out.printf( "Consumer guesses  ", buffer );
   return buffer;
}
```

And in producer I have a random number set in the Buffer. I want to be able to do the same with the consumer, without overwriting

Comment: Why **un**-synchronized?

Comment: to be honest, i'm quite new to this and this is the only one that kinda suited what I needed and I could make it work

Comment: a) java.util.concurrent contains a selection of synchronized data structures. b) It isn't clear how the buffer should work for data exchange (?) between consumer and producer. c) It is, most certainly, possible to do all of that. d) Show some code you have, and where you run into a problem, an exception, an error...

Comment: i've updated my question

Comment: If you have a couple of *classes* accessing an instance of your Buffer class, you don't have to worry. Only if you are running multiple *Thread* instances, which, apparently you don't. -  The methios you've posted can't throw InterruptedException because they don't block.

Comment: the consumer and the producer are both threads, but each only store one value in the buffer at a time. or that's what i want them to do. right now i can only get one of them to store the value.

Comment: But of course you can set or get the buffer value from any thread having access to the Buffer instance. - A *consumer* should never *store* a value in a buffer. - Post some real, complete code - this isn't getting you anywhere.